# JUnit Test for Java SQL Connection and create statements

Tags: java, sql, junit

I have a java file that has connection strings and simple create and select sql statements. So how can I write a JUnit test to make sure it works or not? The file doesn't have main method according to project description.

Comment: Describe what you have tried so far and show some sample code please.

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Read a tutorial on Junit, write a test, and ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: You could use [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) to test your SQL statements.  Were you only interested in testing your queries and results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test a connection, but you have to use a framework like mockito to mock the JDNI resources, you can see an example in:

[How to mock InitialContext constructor in unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734275/how-to-mock-initialcontext-constructor-in-unit-testing/44096460#44096460)

it's works (i test just a few minutes ago), good luck ;)