# How to get InitialContext value in test class

Tags: java, spring, junit, initial-context

I am trying to Mock the `InitialContext` Value to my test class, but was getting the below exception.

> Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial.

1. I tried using `@Mock` and `@Injectmocks`
2. I used the below code in my test class

   ```
   when((DataSource) ctx.lookup("Database name")).thenReturn(dataSource);
   ```

   but still getting the same excpetion.

The complete test method:

```
public void getdetails() { 

  MainclassObj mainclassObj=new MainclassObj(); 
  InitialContext ctx = Mockito.mock(InitialContext.class); 

  when((DataSource) ctx.lookup("Database name")).thenReturn(dataSource); 
  //This is the manin class where DB call is made.
  mainclassObj.getRequiredData(String value); 
  when(response.getStaus).thenReturn(200); 
}
```

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post the full test class so we can see more background details...

Comment: [Spring test](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#mock-objects-jndi) ships with a [mock JNDI environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/jndi/package-summary.html). Or use something like [Simple JNDI](https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI) to provide a JNDI environment for testing.

Comment: Please find the test method below.

public void getdetails() {

 MainclassObj mainclassObj=new  MainclassObj();        
        InitialContext ctx = Mockito.mock(InitialContext.class);
 when((DataSource) ctx.lookup("Database name")).thenReturn(dataSource);
 //This is the manin class where DB call is made.
 mainclassObj.getRequiredData(String value);
 when(response.getStaus).thenReturn(200);     
       
    }

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734275/how-to-mock-initialcontext-constructor-in-unit-testing?