# Mock the Intial Context

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

How to mock the below method using Mockito or PowerMock without providing the class in PrepareForTest

```
class Test{
    public static void test(){
        getConnection();
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {
        InitialContext localInitialContext = new InitialContext();
        DataSource localDataSource = (DataSource) localInitialContext.lookup(JNDINames.DATASOURCE);
        Connection localConnection = localDataSource.getConnection();
        return localConnection;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this question, is `Test` the class you are testing or a dependency of the class you are testing? It's a bit unclear what you mean by 'without providing the class' - do you mean without mocking the class? If so, then the answer is that you can't mock a method without mocking the object it is a member of.

Comment: If you use PowerMockito you will add the class to PrepareForTest with class name and it will affect the coverage and I dont want to use that way of implementation.Is there any other way to mock this class

Comment: what do you think about _offline-instrumentation_?

Comment: But It is not helping in jacoco coverage.

Answer (score 0):

### Tried this below link and it helped to resolve the issue, Thanks

[How to mock InitialContext constructor in unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734275/how-to-mock-initialcontext-constructor-in-unit-testing)